# Is it possible to use an Azure KeyVault with RBAC on an Azure Pipeline Agent?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I setup an Azure Keyvault for my development environment, using the recommendation of RBAC over access policies for authorisation. I've setup other pipelines using on premise agents which access this keyvault via a service principal, and work perfectly fine, but my Azure agents fail with a warning:

```
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\r\nCaller: appid=REDACTED;oid=REDACTED;iss=https://sts.windows.net/REDACTED/\r\nVault: MY-KEYVAULT;location=REDACTED","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}}}
```

I then decided to go back and read some get started guides [like this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-up-azure-key-vault-access-policies), and came across the following note:

```
Note:
Azure Key Vaults that use Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) are not supported.
```

Is there no way to setup a KeyVault to allow access from an Azure Pipeline agent using the recommended RBAC setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\r\nCaller: appid=REDACTED;oid=REDACTED;iss=https://sts.windows.net/REDACTED/\r\nVault: MY-KEYVAULT;location=REDACTED","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}}}

From the error message, it seems that your azure keyvault has enabled firewall.

You could try to add the Azure Pipeline agent IP to the Azure keyvault firewall white list. Since the IPs of Azure Pipelines Agent are not fixed, you can use  script to obtain current IP and add to Azure KeyVault firewall.

Then you could use the Azure Key vault Task to download the key vaults.

Finally, you could remove the Ip rule.

Here is my sample:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: serviceconnection
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "keyvaultname" -IpAddressRange "$IP"
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0

- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: kevin0225'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: serviceconnection
    KeyVaultName: kevin0225

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: serviceconnection
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Remove-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "keyvaultname" -IpAddressRange "$IP"
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

Here is a doc about the method to [add IP to azure keyvault firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security#use-azure-powershell).

Comment: Interesting workaround, thanks!